# SQL Query Refactoring Possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, refactoring

- Assume this is part of the result set

AND

- Assume Dob,Name,Adress,Postcode,Telephone,EmailAddress are the same for each ID - and these columns are used in the group by clause

Sample data:

```
ID      date        Amount
---------------------------
12345   1/1/2017    100
12345   1/2/2017    200
12345   1/3/2017    300
```

With the outer query included I get the following which is what I want to achieve

```
ID      date        Amount
--------------------------
12345   1/1/2017    600
```

I want to confirm if there's a better way in terms of performance for this code. I feel like I could do a join, or a shorter version of the query but I can't get the logic right.

When I remove the outer query and do the MIN and SUM aggregate functions inside, the results doesn't group by correctly. It'll show more than one result for each id.

Also is it possible for a shorter group by?

Here's the partial version of the final code

```
SELECT
    a.id, a.dob, a.claim_id, 
    a.name, a.Address, a.postcode, 
    a.Telephone, a.EmailAdress,
    MIN(a.date), SUM(a.amount) as Amount
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         i.date, i.id, cl.name, cl.address,
         cl.postcode, cl.telephone, cl.dob,
         cl.EmailAdress, i.amount, cm.claim_id
     FROM
         testdb.dbo.invoice i
     JOIN
         testdb.dbo.claim cm with (nolock) ON i.id = cm.id
     JOIN
         testdb.dbo.clients cl with (nolock) ON cm.clientid = cl.id
     JOIN
         (....) c ON i.id = c.id
     WHERE
         .....) AS a
GROUP BY 
    a.id, a.dob, a.claim, a.name, a.Address,
    a.postcode, a.Telephone, a.EmailAdress
ORDER BY
    1
```

Comment: if all columns are the same for the same id, you could group by id and select MIN of other columns. Also when you have just the inner select, do you use distinct and still get multiple records?

Comment: if this code works correctly and all your asking is to make it better then you can submit it on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ahh, didn't know about code review. Thanks!

Comment: @artm using MIN would work. I tried running without the outer query again and it turns out fine now. I'm not sure what happened and what differs now and then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    i.date ,i.id ,cl.name ,cl.address
    ,cl.postcode ,cl.telephone,cl.dob
    ,cl.EmailAdress ,i.amount ,cm.claim_id
FROM 
    testdb.dbo.invoice i
JOIN
    testdb.dbo.claim cm with (nolock) on i.id = cm.id
JOIN 
    testdb.dbo.clients cl with (nolock) on cm.clientid = cl.id
JOIN 
    ( .... ) c on i.id = c.id
WHERE  
    ..... 
GROUP BY
    i.id,i.dob,cm.claim_id,cl.name,cl.Address,cl.postcode,
    cl.Telephone,cl.EmailAdress
ORDER BY 1
```

Is pretty much the previous code. With the outer query removed. I'm not sure what happened previously and as to why it still gave me multiple records(I'm not sure what differed now and then). But it isn't doing that anymore with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the calculation inline and then join the detail tables afterwards,
something like:

```
SELECT
  a.id, a.dob, claimDetails.claim_id, 
  a.name, a.Address, a.postcode, 
  a.Telephone, a.EmailAdress,
  claimDetails.FirstDate, claimDetails.Amount
FROM a  
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT i.id, cm.claim_id, MIN(i.date) as FirstDate, SUM(i.amount) as Amount
   FROM testdb.dbo.invoice i
   JOIN testdb.dbo.claim cm ON i.id = cm.id
   GROUP BY i.id, cm.claim_id
) claimDetails
ON claimDetails.id = a.id
LEFT JOIN Clients....
```